# Python Test sensors, then run them all again until keypress

Tags: python, loops, time, sensors

I`m making a python program for my small greenhouse to test different condition.
What I need it to do is: when the program ends, wait 5 min then run all the tests again.
This is my first ever full python program, so if you can keep the answer in the low learing curve area it would be greatly appriciated.

example:

```
temp=probe1  
humidity=probe2  
CO2=probe3  

if temp==25:  
      print ("25)"  
if humidity==90:  
      print ("90")  
if CO2==1000  
      print ("1000")  

import time  
time.sleep (300) 
start again from top until keypress
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put what you have now in a `while True` [loop](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) to achieve the desired result. This will run forever, making measurements every 5 minutes, until you interrupt the program by pressing Ctrl-C.

```
import time
while True:
    temp=probe1  
    humidity=probe2  
    CO2=probe3  

    if temp==25:  
          print ("25") 
    if humidity==90:  
          print ("90")  
    if CO2==1000  
          print ("1000")    
    time.sleep (300)
```

However, I'm left wondering how likely it is that your sensors give precisely the values you check for. You might go without any output for hours or even longer, depending on the precision of the sensor values. You might want to check the rounded sensor values, e.g. `if round(temp) == 25`.

Or maybe you want to know when `temp` is 25 or higher, which you can check with `if temp >= 25`.

Another possibility would be to always print the sensor data, and print an extra warning in case the values are higher than some threshold, e.g.:

```
import time
while True:
    temp=probe1  
    humidity=probe2  
    CO2=probe3  

    print("Temp:", temp, "degrees")
    if temp>=25:  
          print ("  Too hot!")  

    print("Humidity:", humidity, "%")
    if humidity>=90:  
          print ("  Too humid!")  

    print("CO2:", CO2, "units")
    if CO2>=1000  
          print ("  Too much CO2!")    
    time.sleep (300)
```